# angular location redirect still runs the current controller, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, redirect

i am trying to redirect from a page to another one. Each page has it's own controller.

i do

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.settings = Helper.getLS('settings');
    if (!$scope.settings) $location.path("/app/settings");
    console.log('why am i seeing this?');

...
```

the URL is changing but the issue is that i can still see the log in the console and the rest of the functions in this page still run

i would like to halt execution and redirect and run the other controller on the new page

any ideas?

Comment: You need to `return;` just do `if (!$scope.settings) return $location.path("/app/settings");`

Comment: dammit, you were right. you can post the response and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the path you need to exit out of the function, inorder to avoid the rest of the code form being executed. `$location.path()` does not halt the code and redirect. So just do:-

```
      if (!$scope.settings) {
         return $location.path("/app/settings");
      }
      //Rest of the code
```